# Environment for developing both Windows Phone 8.1 and Universal Windows apps

Tags: xamarin, uwp, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I am an experienced dev that haven't been writing too much code lately, so a bit rusty and would like to have some help in creating the right environment for developing apps for BOTH Win Phone 8.1 (which is what I am carrying on me and would like to test with) and also Win 10 apps (UWP). This is in order to save myself a lot of time in trial and error, which is what I have been doing lately without success.

I have a box at home that is now Windows 10, and I think it was Windows 8 when I bought it. It has both VS 2013 and VS 2015, and I tried to download all the right SDK's to be able to use the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator. It was a nightmare, including going to the BIOS and enabling the Hyper-V thing (I think it worked at some point). Currently I'm having too many problems related to the dev environment, and its getting frustrating. Even the Win 10 emulator is not working. So no UWP emulator nor Windows Phone 8.1 emulator for me right now.

So instead of tackling these problems one by one, my plan is to buy myself a new laptop and build it right, with everything that I need in order to be able to write both Win Phone 8.1 apps, as well as Xamarin, and Windows 10 apps.

I'm wondering if I can ask for a comprehensive list of specifications for me, including recommended OS version (Will Win 7 work? I prefer it), VS version, SDK's, etc.. My goal is that after I buy and setup this laptop, all i'll have to do is just choose the right project and start writing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, downvoted just like that - not sure why so much.

If someone is looking for an answer or pointer, here's a reply in another [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c608deb6-c53b-4756-bfd8-4422b86bbe30/environment-for-developing-both-windows-phone-81-and-universal-windows-apps?forum=wpdcapp), which helped me at least:

> VS 2017 does not support development of Windows 8.1 store apps - phone or PC. See this link for platform compatibility. You will need to fallback to using VS 2015 for any Windows 8.1 projects. I do Windows 8.1 and 10 development on a single system and it works fine. You just have to have both VS 2015 & 2017 installed. Windows 7 will not work for developing 8.1 and 10 apps. Windows 8.1 has a Universal app target that allowed you to create a single app for PC and phone (I've never used it), but it is nothing like the Windows 10 UWP platform.

Comment: Phone 8.1 is dead next month as MS stops support for Phone 8.1. So move directly to UWP and Windows 10 (Mobile) only

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with WP 8.1 for a while since most carriers are not updating .. so need to test somehow ...

Comment: this is unrelated to carriers. users have to install an app to check win10mobile compatibility and if the phone is supported, it offeres Win10mobile

Comment: Don't neglect Windows Phone 8.1, most WP phones are WP8.1 not Windows 10 Mobile. Windows Phone 8.1 apps work on WP8.1 AND on Win10Mobile, but UWP apps only work on Win10Mobile.